# Present Perfect Continuous or Present Continuous

Tags: present-tense

My teacher is going to tell me the results of my last exam. And I want to use a verb "wait."

Should I tell:

I am waiting for the results.

or

I have been waiting for the results.

What I want to emphasize is that I have passed already one test and (wait) for the last results.

Comment: You can't "emphasize that you have passed already one test" unless you actually ***say*** that. The fact that you're waiting for [some] results implies nothing about whether you've already passed (and received notification thereof) some *other* test.

Comment: /I have been waiting for the results/ implies a period of time [for two week, for three hours, for ten minutes, since last night, since yesterday]. And you can't say I am waiting for the results [since or for x]. That would be a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

From a native speaker:

An excellent question on tone of voice.  "I am waiting for the results" is best, as a neutral request for results, not a complaint.  When you say, "I have been waiting for the results," you suggest you are impatient. You are saying you have been waiting all this very long time.  That tone does not produce good results with someone above you like a teacher, and it is harsh when you are the one with authority.

Answer (score 0):

I am waiting for the results. PRESENT: implication: This is what I am doing now.

or

I have been waiting for the results [since yesterday, since this morning, for three days, for ten minutes.]

**USUALLY, one specifies a period of time using FOR OR SINCE with the present perfect continuous. Or that time period is implied or understood to exist.**

Answer (score -1):

I want to say: I have already passed one test and (I want to use the verb "wait"here in the correct form).

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/218586)